# In Excel I need to Replace cell values if it matches

Tags: excel, vlookup

In my Excel file I have two sheet and below is the Structure.
If one or multiple values under "TC iD Column" matches with first Column in sheet 2 then it ids in Sheet one will replace with URL or displayed in the next column in sheet.

Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet 1 Contents the data in below format]

Sheet 2:

[[image]]

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? And are those individual cells in your first picture, or what?

Comment: Your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. One can try an OCR program, or manually enter it. Having to do either of these is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sub jain()

Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet, xrow1 as long, xrow2 as long, xcol as Int, ID as string
set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
xrow1 = 2
xrow2 = 2
xcol = 3

do until ws1.Cells(xrow1, 2) = ""
    do until ws2.Cells(xrow2, 2) = ""    
        ID = ws2.Cells(xrow2, 1).value
        if InStr(1, ws1.Cells(xrow1, 2), ID) > 0 Then
            ws1.Cells(xrow1, xcol).value = ws2.Cells(xrow2, 1).value        
            xcol = xcol + 1
        else:
        End if
    xrow2 = xrow2 + 1
    loop
xrow2 = 2
xcol = 3
loop

end sub
```

basically this will loop through each cell and check if there is an id match. when there is one, the InStr function will result in a value of 1, making the if trigger which copies the hyperlink from sheet2 to the cells to the right of the ID column in sheet1.

I made this assuming that on sheet1, the TC ID column is the second column, that the hyperlink column in sheet2 is the second column (and that sheet has headers), and that all the cells to the right of the TC ID column on sheet1 are blank.  If any of these assumptions are wrong I will need to change values in the code for it to work properly.

I didn't test this so if you get errors let me know and I can fix it.